ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL' while I installed this package
Traceback(most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\AlarmTran\nifti2dicom-main\nifti2dicom-main\main.py", line 11, in <module>
    import PIL
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL'

Although I successfuly installed this package,t his problem still appeared:

I use Windows 10.

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

because it's Pillow not pillow...

How many versions of Python do you have? Run py -0p to check
